# Disassembly - Why the CMP instruction is multiplying by 2 the value being compared

Tags: disassembly, ollydbg, debuggers, disassemblers, crackme

I'll get right to the point, I have a crack me program, that is a program with a password inside that needs to be found so that you can complete the challenge.

I easily **found the cmp instruction** with the password, **but the numeric password was multiplied by 2.**

in the program **does not have anything to multiply** or divide the password, then this must be caused by something else

so I had to get the hexadecimal value of the password convert to decimal and **divide by 2** to have the *real* password.

here is the cmp instruction:

```
CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-C],961DB0
```

> 0x961DB0 / 2 is the password.
>   EBP-C has the password.

I would like to know why the password has been multiplied by 2 in this cmp instruction.

[image: OLLYDBG SEEING THE PASSWORD]

A photo of the Source Code, I do not have it without being in the photo.

[image: SOURCE CODE !!]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you replace those photos with the real code? It will make question better and reproducible for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cmp` instruction does not multiply anything by two. Instead, the piece of code seen in your ollydbg screen shot is the implementation of the following line from the poor quality source code image you attached:

```
if ((!key) || (key > (0x1337 * 2000)))
```

First, in address `0x01051C09`, `key` is compared to `0`. If `key` equals `0` a jump to `0x01051C18` is taken. Otherwise, `key` is compared to `0x0961DB0`. If `key` is below or equal to `0x0961DB0` another jump is taken. If `key` is *greater* than `0x0961DB0` execution continues to `0x01051C18`.

As you should've guessed by now, `0x0961DB0` is simply `0x1337` times 2000.

Instructions `0x01051C18` to `0x01051C22` are the implementation of calling `wrong`, setting `eax` to the correct return value (`1`) and then jumping to where (I assume) the function prolog and `ret` are executed.

Comment: Thanks, but suppose we did not have the source code, how could we identify that 0x0961DB0 is 0x1337 * 2000?

Comment: We would not necessarily recognise that. Instead, we may write condition as `key > 0x0961DB0`. It's essentially the same.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for clarifying the problem.